# How to pronounce [ɮˤ]

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics

When attempting to produce it, I move my tongue to the top-left back teeth where I make a sound which resembles a drowned out [d͡z]. If I misplace my tongue here, this devolves into a trilled [r].
What am I doing wrong here, what is the proper technique here for the sound?

Comment: Murshad, this is not really an Arabic language forum.

Comment: (Oh I forgot to mention, I asked about the on/off-topicness [on the meta](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/q/764/2795).)

Comment: I have accepted the edit. The question now asks about how to learn to make a particular sound rather than about the characteristics of a particular language.

Comment: lads: for example, That cannot become a trilled r.

Answer (score -3):

dad == أب

Like "Up" in "7UP"